# how to get the content size of a view

Tags: objective-c

i am just beginner of iphone programming . i want to get size(full size) of content for scrollview can any one please provide me solution .
            Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIScrollView has a content size property:

```
@property(nonatomic) CGSize contentSize
```

For future reference, I found this in the [UIScrollView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).